# What's the most Pythonic way to refactor this list building code?

Tags: dry, python

I have a list of results that I need to pull out various other lists from. For example, all owners that are male, all cars between 5 and 10 years old.

```
def get_male_owners(self):
    results = []
    for result in self.results:
        if result.owner.sex.male:
            results.append(result)
    return results

def get_cars_5_to_10(self):
    results = []
    for result in self.results:
        if result.car:
            if self.is_5_to_10(result.car):
                results.append(result)
    return results

def is_5_to_10(self, car):
    if car.age <= 10 and car.age >= 5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The thing is there will be lots of different lists I need to build, but a lot of the code in each of the list building functions is common. What's the best way to implement DRY in a Pythonic way here? Thanks.

Comment: There is no "most pythonic" way. There are Pythonic ways, yes, but not "most pythonic" except for extremely simple cases. For example, list comprehensions are usually seen as Pythonic (as in this case) but can sometimes be too complex to be readable which makes them unpythonic. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use list comprehensions:

```
def get_male_owners(self):
    return [res for res in self.results if res.owner.sex.male]

def get_cards_5_to_10(self):
    return [res for res in self.results if res.car and self.is_5_to_10(res.car)]

def is_5_to_10(self, car):
    return 5 <= car.age <= 10
```

If you just need something iterable you could also return a generator expression by replacing the brackets with parentheses.

And yes, the `x <= y <= z` expression does work in python and it does yield the correct result and not something like `(5 <= car.age) <= 10`.

Comment: fixed. (and this minimum comment length sucks)

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter(self, by=None):
    return [res for res in self.results if by(res)]

def get_male_owners(self):
    return self.filter(lambda res: res.owner.sex.male)
```

Comment: Didn't you mean `self.filter` instead of `self.get`?

Comment: what if your filter method is called without providing any function for the argument by ? There is no check on if by is not None. Also python has builtin function filter and naming your method same as python builtin might not be a good idea.